# emphasise some observation weights more than the others

Tags: weighted-data

I want to emphasise (increase the weight) of only a subset of data. Lets say I have old and fresh data, I would like to say that old data has to have more weight and therefore has more influence in the decision than the new data.

In scikit-learn I found only `class-weight` parameter, but it does not change the weight of the samples, only of all samples within the class.

Is there a way to incorporate this emphasis into the gradient boosted trees in spark or xgboost in python?

Comment: Are you sure it does that? The [documentation suggests otherwise](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html); see `sample_weight_last_ten`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date variable (or something similar), you can create a weight using this.

If you're using XGBoost, there is an option to specify a `weight` for each instance when creating the `DMatrix` - feed your observation weighting in here.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a fancier way to create dynamic weights but I would probably start with oversampling the subset and see how that goes. So if you've got classes A, B, and C and want to emphasize C, make a duplicate copy of C and insert that into your training data. In other words, assume you have six records to train on:

1. A1
2. A2
3. B1
4. B2
5. C1
6. C2

**add:**

7. C1
8. C2

Comment: You should be very wary of this method as it may introduce biases and skewness into your data - e.g. the distribution of certain variables may change.